# What is the syntax errror here?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i'm trying to forward engineer this code for the database to be created but i'm getting this error:

for the right syntax to use near 'INVISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_TANQUE_COMBUSTIVEL1`
      FOREIGN KEY (`COMBUSTIVEL_i' at line 9

```
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.`TANQUE`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TANQUE` (
          `idTANQUE` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
          `QteCombustivel` INT NOT NULL,
          `COMBUSTIVEL_idCOMBUSTIVEL` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`idTANQUE`, `COMBUSTIVEL_idCOMBUSTIVEL`),
          INDEX `fk_TANQUE_COMBUSTIVEL1_idx` (`COMBUSTIVEL_idCOMBUSTIVEL` ASC) INVISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_TANQUE_COMBUSTIVEL1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`COMBUSTIVEL_idCOMBUSTIVEL`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`COMBUSTIVEL` (`idCOMBUSTIVEL`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 6 succeeded, 1 failed

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Did you check the documentation for that version to see if `INVISIBLE` was a viable option for the `INDEX` portion of the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Answer (score 3):

Invisible indexes were introduced in MySQL 8.0. If your server uses the older version, it won't recognize this keyword.

Comment: @Baitalon Depends on your system. Make a new question or look for existing ones.